# How to prevent downloading HTML5 videos

Tags: html, video

I would like to show a video on my website and I know that it would never be 100% guaranteed that the viewer could not download the video from my link.

However, would there be any method so that I can make them difficult to do so without using Flash? Is it possible using HTML5 or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever shown to the user through HTML/JS/CSS cannot be made un-copyable!

And the videos you are talking about, understand how it works:

It gets downloaded to user's pc, and then it is run.

so there is no way without getting this downloaded to user's pc.

Comment: I know there is no way to prevent it. But can I make it difficult to do so? At least the viewer can not download my video by just simply right click on the mouse, or just copy a link. They may need to do more to find my link.

Comment: May be this [link](http://www.webpagemistakes.ca/disable-right-click/) will help you a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently impossible via HTML5 Multimedia. You can't prevent someone from downloading your media.

Answer (score 0):

I heard there's going to be a DRM system for videos. I don't know if that's what you want, but it might be a problem solver for you. Meaning you can secure your videos with a password, or require the viewer to be online while watching.

If I'm not mistaken it isn't implemented yet, but they're busy with it.